# How to avoid circular dependency when using Dagger component dependency

Tags: java, dagger-2

How to avoid circular dependency across Dagger Components

Let's say I have library with two interfaces: `Engine`, and `Car`.

```
package com.library;
interface Engine {}
```

```
package com.library;
interface Car {}
```

The library also contains an implementation: `MyCar`, but importantly, *not* an implementation of `Engine`:

```
package com.library;
class MyCar implements Car {
    public MyCar(Engine engine) {}
}
```

I have an application that depends on this library. The application contains an implementation of `Engine`

```
package com.application;
class HybridEngine implements Engine {
    public HybridEngine(...) {} 
}
```

I now want to use Dagger to satisfy these dependencies. Library and Application each have a Dagger Module and Dagger Component. I set application component to depend on library component:

```
package com.library;
@Module
public class LibraryModule {
    @Provides
    @LibraryScope
    Car provideCar(Engine engine) {
        return new MyCar(engine);
    }
}
```

```
package com.library;
@LibraryScope
@Component(modules = {LibraryModule.class})
public interface LibraryComponent {
}
```

```
package com.application;
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    @Provides
    @ApplicationScope
    Engine provideEngine() {
        return new HybridEngine();
    }
}
```

```
package com.application;
@ApplicationScope
@Component(
        modules = {ApplicationModule.class},
        dependencies = {LibraryComponent.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent { }
```

I then create these components in my Application:

```
onCreate() {
    LibraryComponent libraryComponent = DaggerLibraryComponent.builder()
            .build();

    ApplicationComponent appComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .libraryComponent(libraryComponent)
            .build();
}
```

This creates a problem. In order to supply `LibraryComponent` with an `Engine` (to then satisfy `MyCar`'s dependency) I have to use `@BindsInstance` inside `LibraryComponent`:

```
package com.library;
@LibraryScope
@Component(modules = {LibraryModule.class})
public interface LibraryComponent {

    Car getCar();

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        LibraryComponent.Builder bindEngine(Engine engine);

        LibraryComponent build();
    }
}
```

The component creation then looks like this:

```
public void onCreate() {
    Engine engine = ...
    LibraryComponent libraryComponent = DaggerLibraryComponent.builder()
            .bindEngine(engine)
            .build();

    ApplicationComponent appComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .libraryComponent(libraryComponent)
            .build();
}
```

But I don't know how to get access to an `Engine`. I can create one *outside* the object graph. But I need the Engine created *by the object graph* so that I can supply *its* dependencies (which I have not shown). How can I do this?

In other words, how can a parent component provide an object to the dependent component, if that object has its own dependencies that need to be supplied by the parent component?

*You can thank me later for not using a Thermosiphon example*

---

UPDATE

After taking @Denvercoder9 's suggestions I removed `@BindsInstance` and LibraryComponent.Builder. I then added `@Inject` to HybridEngineConstructor

```
package com.application;
class HybridEngine implements Engine {
    @Inject public HybridEngine() { }
}
```

I then added a `@Named` annotation:

```
package com.application;

@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    @Named("HybridEngine")
    @Provides
    @ApplicationScope
    Engine provideEngine() {
        return new HybridEngine();
    }
```

```
package com.library;
@Module
public class LibraryModule {
    @Provides
    @LibraryScope
    Car provideCar(@Named("HybridEngine") Engine engine) {
        return new MyCar(engine); 
   }
}
```

However I'm now getting a build error:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] @javax.inject.Named("HybridEngine") com.library.Engine cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public interface LibraryComponent {
       ^
```

Comment: Just slap `@Inject` to `HybridEngine`'s constructor and add a named or qualifier annotation for engine in `provideCar` and `provideEngine` funcs. That should work without any bindsinstance shenanigans

Comment: @denvercoder9 tried that, got a new error (see updated OP)